# Why doesn't my viewpager work in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator

I have the following code for my fragment. I pretty much took this from a basic view pager example and slapped it into a fragment to test for a project I'm working on.

I'm using ACtionBarSherlock, and viewPagerIndicator libraries. The Fragment below contains a viewPager that in this example is supposed to swipe between simple title strings.

I tried the example with the ViewPager and ViewPagerIndicator in an activity, and no problem. But the second I put it into a fragment. BOOM, nothing but a black screen... NO errors, just a black screen...I feel like I must be inflating, or accessing the layout incorrectly or something...
Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
public class TestFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    //~Constants----------------------------------------------


    //~Data Fields--------------------------------------------

    //~Constructors--------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Setup view
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = onCreateView(getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState), null, savedInstanceState);

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( this.getSherlockActivity() );
        ViewPager pager = 
            (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.free_time_day_pager);
        TitlePageIndicator indicator = 
            (TitlePageIndicator)view.findViewById(R.id.titles);
        pager.setAdapter( adapter );
        indicator.setViewPager( pager );
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.free_time_fragment_layout, null, false);
        return view;
    }

    //~Methods-------------------------------------------------
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont call `onCreateView` that is wrong.

`onCreateView` is an overridden method which is called by the `FragmentManger` to handle the `Fragment` lifecycle.

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TitlePagerIndicator mIndicator;

// Called first
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Setup view
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

// Called second
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.free_time_fragment_layout, null, false);
    return view;
}

// Called third
@Override
public View onViewCreated(View v){
    super.onViewCreated(v);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.free_time_day_pager);
    mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)v.findViewById(R.id.titles);

}


public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bdl){
    super.onActivityCreated(bdl);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( getSherlockActivity() );
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
}
```

Also be aware if you are using a FragmentPagerAdapter you require a special method to create the ViewPagerFragment, its a bit tricky but refer to this [gist.](https://gist.github.com/3405429)

Read about `Fragment` Lifecycles [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle) too.

Cheers

Comment: !!! You sir have opened my eyes to this fragment business! thank you so much! Now I can go implement this strategy in my application and have it stop looking ugly!!

Comment: They are the way forward so please use them. Make Phone and tablet layouts soo much easier. Also use them for Dialogs too, makes maintaining the dialog lifecycle so much easier. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#AlertDialog

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

work for me.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Comment: My question pre-dated gradle, but I'm glad to see that this question has been answered for the tools of today!